# info presented to the user in a payments page

Tags: design-patterns

I am in the stage where I will start building the page of my app that displays the payment status of the user.

Nonetheless I have no idea what this page will look like from a content point of view.

What are you think are the 2-3 more important aspects of such a page...**what kind of info should it present to the user.** I am assuming nothing...

Answer (score 2):

You’re assuming correct: Nothing is the answer! A payment page shouldn’t distract the user from the crucial process of paying for the items or services she are about to pay for. Only relevant information absolutely necessary for the payment should be there. No other services or items to buy and no advertisement.

The only thing that should be there is what is necessary for the user to (1) feel comfortable that she is still at the place where she is buying, (2) that she is paying for the items/services and finally (3) the payment information. Nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question right. I assume that you're asking about the "user settings section", where the user can click on "My Payment" or something else.

In this case the first and most important thing is to show if the user has an active "premium" account or paid for the service (on-off payment or subscription).

To Show:
  Which product bought the user?
  (optional) Link to a list of premium functions
  Date + time of payment
  Price + currency
  (if Subscription) next renewal date + time
  Paid with: "Credit card".... (please do not show the credit card number :) )
  Link to the invoice

If the user didn't buy any product, then just show some text informing the user about his "FREE usage" or something else.
And most important to show some upselling teaser. Show what the user can get if he buy your product + measure link to get a conversion rate.

Comment: one clarification...the user will pay for a service...more or less...I have concluded to this logic: display info about the type of account(premium etc)...display info for what months he has paid(assuming for example a 3 month period)...one last question is when someone pays for a period(1 month for exampl)...the subscription starts from the day he made the payment?

Comment: regading your question: normally the subscription starts with the successful payment (except it do not make sense for you).